# Best way to change JSON keys with JACKSON or other java lib

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I have a Json file or string for example:

```
{
  "my-key0": "ke0",
  "key-Arr": [
    {
      "nested-key1": {
        "value": "val",
        "seqno": 12
      },
      "nested2": 1
    },
    {
      "dns-sss-qqq": [
        {
          "some": "aaaaa"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "recsize": 459,
  "my-obj": {
    "my-key1": {
      "my-key2": "key2"
    }
  }
}
```

My purpose is to  replace "-" char to "_" char only in keys in Scala/Java.

In first I thought it can be done with REGEX but the keys can be UNQUOTED and it also can effect on values.
What is most efficient way to it?(Performance is matter)
I have to process GBs of such records.
Thank you

Comment: If the keys are unquoted, then it is not valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

Comment: I suppose the schema isn't the same for all records?

Comment: @XavierGuihot  There are a lot of types of Schemas

Comment: @Andreas In Jackson Lib you have an option to set unquoted keys valid
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES,true)

Comment: @Alex That might be true, but allowing the parser to be lenient still doesn't make the input valid JSON.

Comment: @Andreas Ok, and if I have only quoted key, what is best way to replace keys?

Comment: Best way is likely using the Jackson Streaming API, so you won't have to store all those GBs in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) - [it supports *kebab-case* since v0.17.0](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/commit/dc0e790832e5725960253c3f51d363760a7de230#diff-c0728d9d425efa9c2ec832d7c3fcea00) and also it is more efficient in parsing and serialization than `jackson-module-scala`.

[Here are latest results](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json) of benchmarks which compare parsing & serialization performance of `jsoniter-scala` vs. `jackson-module-scala`, `circe` and `play-json` libraries using JDK 8.

Also it has ability to [parse streaming JSON values and JSON arrays from `java.io.InputStream`](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/bc450c9e8f56e1719669a3e629eb89b764be553b/jsoniter-scala-core/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/core/package.scala#L55-L83) w/o need of holding all parsed values in the memory.

Extraction of some selected fields or substructures instead of parsing whole message or document is where jsoniter-scala shines.

So try just use it instead of conversion of all your data.